# Function to make grid of images

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I do not know a lot of Pillow for python. I am trying to make a function to put multiple images into one. If there are 18 images, then the function would make a 3x6 grid of those images. If there is an odd amount of images it will still make the grid but with a blank image. If you know about Fortnite item shop bots, I wish to achieve an image like one of those.

[image: Image I want]

Comment: Are all the base images the same dimensions?

Comment: You don't need to write any Python to do that, you can just use **ImageMagick** in your Terminal or Command Prompt. Say you have 18 files called `image-1.jpg` through `image-18.jpg`, you can do `magick montage -tile 6x3 -geometry +5+5 image*.jpg result.png`

Comment: @AndrewFan They are all the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, imagemagick is probably easier. However, I threw together a barely tested script in Python using PIL to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Usage:
# python3 <name of python file> <number of columns> [ list of filenames of images ]
# Note: First image's dimensions will be used to determine grid size. Assumes all images have the same dimensions.

import sys
import math
from PIL import Image

numcols = int(sys.argv[1])
numimages = len(sys.argv) - 2 # Ignore name of program and column input
numrows = math.ceil(numimages / numcols) # Number of rows

sampleimage = Image.open(sys.argv[2]) # Open first image, just to get dimensions
width, height = sampleimage.size # PIL uses (x, y)

outimg = Image.new("RGBA", (numcols * width, numrows * height), (0, 0, 0, 0)) # Initialize to transparent

# Write to output image. This approach copies pixels from the source image
for i in range(numimages):
    currimage = Image.open(sys.argv[2 + i])
    for j in range(width):
        for k in range(height):
            currimgpixel = currimage.getpixel((j, k))
            outimg.putpixel(((i % numcols * width) + j, (i // numcols * height) + k), currimgpixel)
outimg.save("output.png")
```

It's a little hacky but gets the job done. You feed it the number of columns followed by a list of image file paths, and it will generate the grid of images in output.png. It's not exactly efficient, but it should work as a naive solution.